# Is it possible to display a custom cursor or cursor badge in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, cursor

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/Reference/Reference.html

This shows the available cursors, that are build into Cocoa, its it possible to append a custom png to the cursor using built-in methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [`-[NSCursor initWithImage:hotSpot:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000326-CJBDCEII) followed by [`-[NSCursor set]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000326-set)?

Comment: But don't use custom cursors unless absolutely necessary!

Comment: it would be more of a custom badge on a cursor, like a you can't drop that object here badge